Finding the Max of a Discrete Probability Distribution
I have a discrete random variable $X$ with $N$ possible values and some distribution

Suppose that there is some $X_m$ such that
$$
P(X_m) > P(X_j),\quad\forall\ j \neq m
$$
Suppose that the gap to the second largest probability is $\delta$.
I'm trying to figure out how many samples I'd need ( in terms of $N$ ) to find $X_m$.

If you know of any references I can look into, I'd really appreciate it

Do you know the difference between the largest and second-largest probabilities? The number of samples you need (for a certain level of confidence) will depend on this quantity

@AlanChung I've edited the question to add this additional piece of info. Thanks!

I added an additional edit below containing some intuition

So here is a general sketch of how you can solve the problem. Consider the simpler case that $N=2$, so that there are only two possible values $X_1$ and $X_2$, where $P(X_1) > P(X_2).$ Then if you have $M$ samples, can you compute the probability $p$ that there are more samples that equal $X_1$ than $X_2$? Note that here, $P(X_1) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\delta)$ and $P(X_2) = \frac{1}{2} (1-\delta),$ so this probability $p$ should be in terms of $M$ and $\delta$.
Hence, if you want a certain level of confidence in your test, like you want this probability $p$ to be higher than $0.95$, then you can solve for the value of $M$ that gives you $p=0.95$, and that's how many samples you need. I think if I were to guess, the number of samples should be on the order of $\delta \sqrt{M}$ or something. Then you can extend this procedure to higher $N$.
Edit: some intuition as to why the $\sqrt{M}$ term should appear. When $N=2$, the fraction of samples that equal $X_1$ is a Binomial distribution with mean $q=\frac{1}{2}(1+\delta)$ and variance $\frac{q(1-q)}{M},$ and hence standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{q(1-q)}{M}}.$ We can approximate it with a normal distribution with standard deviation of order $\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}.$ Since the normal distribution contains most of its probability mass within a few standard deviations, the number of samples you need satisfies something like $O(1/\sqrt{M}) < \delta.$
